# Resharper tool - fix violation "Parameter names must match base type definition"

Tags: plugins, resharper

I have a big source code, which has thousands of violations for the rule "Parameter names must match base type definition"

I am in search of a tool/resharper utility that does this job .

Is there any such tool already available?

I am trying to develop a resharper plugin for the same. But do not know how to run this as commandline on a given directory.

Regards,
Sunitha